# htmlwidget onRender function does not work in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to put a pulsing marker from a leaflet plugin on a Shiny App Map.
It works very well on a basic R Studio Console, see here : [Add a popup when clicked through to a 'plugin' pulsing marker in R Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623769/add-a-popup-when-clicked-through-to-a-plugin-pulsing-marker-in-r-leaflet)

But the following do not :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #js and css plugin files are stored locally, but you can access to them here :
# https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse/master/src/L.Icon.Pulse.js
# https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse/master/src/L.Icon.Pulse.css
  esriPlugin <- htmlDependency("leaflet-icon-pulse",version = "1.0",
                               src = "C:/HOME/",
                               script = "L.Icon.Pulse.js",stylesheet ="L.Icon.Pulse.css")

  registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
    map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
    map
  }

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter") %>% setView(-122.4105513,37.78250256, zoom = 12) %>%
      registerPlugin(esriPlugin) %>%
      onRender("function(el,x) {
               var pulsingIcon = L.icon.pulse({iconSize:[5,5],color:'red',heartbeat:0.5});
               var pulsingIcon2 = L.icon.pulse({iconSize:[10,10],color:'orange',heartbeat:2});
               var marker = L.marker([37.78,-122.41],{icon: pulsingIcon}).bindPopup('<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.').openPopup().addTo(this);
               var marker = L.marker([37.75,-122.39],{icon: pulsingIcon2}).addTo(this);}")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Anyone see why it do not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like indeed a bug in Shiny (or htmlwidgets), I created a reproducible example and filed an issue 
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1389

Comment: Hi Bhaskar , how r u? Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: I now have a plugin that supports pulse icon. https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras but you'll have to build leaflet from https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet/commits/milestone/v1.1.

Comment: Hi, It seems I'm not able to do what you recommended because by running : library(devtools) ;
dev_mode(on=T) ;
install_github("bhaskarvk/leaflet") ;
install_github("bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras") ; And your RPub code example, I build a map but with no pulsing markers. Can you see where I'm wrong? Thanks Bhaskar

Comment: You need to build the milestone/v1.1 branch , do install_github('bhaskarvk/leaflet@a7b924a')

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot for your patience. Don't know why a7b924a but it's ok I won't bother you anymore!! I'm gonna ask somebody else

Comment: No worries, a7b92a is the latest commit # on the milestone/v-1.1 branch. It would be good for you to learn some basic git and devtools fundamentals. it would go a long way. All the best.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the precision and your piece of advice. Your "package" is great and works fine within a Shiny App, congrats!!